# JMeter If Controller using groovy and Or is not working

Tags: jmeter

I have a script where I have some if controllers. I'm attempting to add a 4th If controller that will trigger a script failure if none of the 3 expected values is returned.  It's saying one of the 3 expected values is invalid.

1st, I have a user defined variable like this:

```
testTool= ${__P(testTool,APPLES)}
```

2nd, I have these 3 If controllers with these Expressions:

1. `${__groovy(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("APPLES"))}`
2. `${__groovy(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("BANANAS"))}`
3. `${__groovy(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("PEACHES"))}`

The 4th If is supposed to be triggered if the value of testTool is not one of the 3 expected values.  It's Expression looks like this:

```
>    ${__groovy( (vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("APPLES") == false || 
>    vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("BANANAS") == false ||
>    vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("PEACHES") == false)) }
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
>  ${__groovy((!vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("APPLES") || 
>  !vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("BANANAS") || 
>  !vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("PEACHES")),)}
```

It is somehow saying APPLES is an invalid testTool.  What am I doing wrong?  All if controllers have the '**Interpret Condition as Variable Expression**' checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `&&` operator instead of `||`, see [Groovy Logical Operators](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_logical_operators) for detailed explanation and more information.

Your 4th expression needs to be amended to look like:

```
${__groovy(!(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("APPLES")) && !(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("BANANAS")) && !(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("PEACHES")))}
```

---

An easier option would be using [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), from implementation and especially performance perspectives it is the optimal solution.

- Add Switch Controller to your Test Plan
- Use `${testTool}` as the "Switch Value"
- Put 4 requests as the children of the Switch Controller and name them as:

  - `APPLES`
  - `BANANAS`
  - `PEACHES`
  - `DEFAULT`

  So if `${testTool}` variable value will be `APPLES` - the `APPLES` sampler will be executed, if `${testTool}` variable value will be `BANANAS` - the `BANANAS` sampler will be executed, etc.

  If `${testTool}` will not match any other children - JMeter will run `DEFAULT` sampler

  [image: JMeter Switch Controller]

See [Selection Statements in JMeter Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy) guide for details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following condition in if controller

```
 ${__groovy(!(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("APPLES"))||!(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("BANANAS"))||!(vars.get("testTool").toUpperCase().equals("PEACHES")))}
```

Please let me know if it helps